# Views: Is it possible to Group "exposed" filters in a <div> and add css to it?

Tags: views, theming

In Drupal 7, I have a Views which contained "content: ID", "Content: Type", "Content: Title", "Content: Organization", Conent: City", "Content: State" and "Date: Date(node)". They are all exposed. How can I group them into 3  groups(the group in rearrange only give the feature to add "and" or "or" group), so I can add CSS and make them as an expandable list. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposed filters appear in a form so you have to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)
as well as [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) to theme any form.

Using hook_form_alter assign a new theme to that particulat form.
hook_theme is usead for register a new theme.

For more information about form theming visit [here](http://data.agaric.com/how-theme-drupal-form)

Comment: I think it will work but looks like very complicated to me :(

Comment: Hi @Rupesh I found an article that can group all exposed filters into a fieldset. Which is http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3058/solved-drupal-views-drupal-7-how-to-place-exposed-filters-in-a-fieldset . Any idea how can I set this for only "ViewsA".

Answer (score 0):

Use [Views exposed groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_exposed_groups).
From the project page:

> Adds a new exposed filter style where exposed filters can be grouped into fieldsets (either traditional fieldsets, collapsed fieldsets, or vertical tabs). This is especially useful when a view has an unwieldily number of exposed filter options.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the [Views Exposed Form Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ef_fieldset) module is probably the way to go as that is actively supported and  has both Drupal 7 and 8 versions.